# How can I tell what JS/HTML5 library this website is using?

Tags: javascript, html

I found this awesome clone of an epic old game called gunbound. It was developed in HTML5/javascript.

I'm wondering if I could find somehow the js/html5 library they are using for this project?

[website](http://dragonbound.net)

I'm trying to look it up because it really inspired me (I'm amazed that this was done in html5) and I'm determined to learn html5 and javascript. I want to follow their steps :)

Comment: There is an js file called DragonBound... if i where you, i should look at that one to start ;-) [http://dragonbound.net/static/js/DragonBound.compiled.js](http://dragonbound.net/static/js/DragonBound.compiled.js)

Comment: I just edited it. Sorry about that. I tried looking up the code but I couldn't find any "popular" html5 library for game developing perhaps they are coding this from the ground up? Is the link showing up in the OP? Anyways, http://dragonbound.net/

Comment: thanks for update, i've updated my answer to an js file of what looks like the game... I think you should start looking at that one...

Comment: Well, they are using Cloudflare, google analytics, socket.io, jquery, jquery-ui, tinyscrollbar, QTransform, soundmanager... `View source` is awesome!

Comment: @TWCrap I can't see your answer.

Comment: @11684, somehow my answer is converted to an comment, so i will post i will repost an answer...

Comment: what library is handling all the game's mechanics?

Comment: @DiegoBurela, look at my answer, there's an link to the main js file. As far as i can see, is there the game (most of it)

Answer (score 3):

It probably uses a `node.js` server. Uses `CloudFlare` for security. For the html part, I think it is based on html5 boilerplate.

- `jQuery`
- `QTransform` for `CSS` transformations
- `socket.io` for server/client communication
- `soundmanager2` for audio

Now the real answer.

developer tools of your browser tells you what script and css files site uses. From that list I provided list above. since it uses `socket.io`, it most likely uses `node.js` for server. if you look at the network tab you will see `Server:cloudflare-nginx` header. This is your cue for `CloudFlare`.

Comment: node.js is used for server related stuff right? I was hoping they were using some pre made commercial engine for the mechanics of the game like http://impactjs.com

It really blows my mind that this was done purely with html5/js it's handling thousands of thousands of people as well.

Comment: You can use wooga's MIT licenced `Pocket Island` game. look at https://github.com/wooga/Pocket-Island

Comment: I will check it out looks good.
I'm afraid to learn or choose something that won't handle a game like dragonbound.

Comment: Try to experiment with node.js for a while. I used it some of my pet projects. It has a massive package library. Many of the libraries are simply takes my breathe away just by looking their code. socket.io, nowjs, express, io9... and many more. get comfy with nodejs and it will make more sense. I solved 50+ of the question of project euler using node.js just to get used with it.

Answer (score 0):

Edokan is right. You need to use the develompent toolkit (i recommend chrome to use) to find all the librarys that are used.

Also can you execute some simple javascript (jquery) code from the console, to see what it does.

If you're looking for the main js file, i recommend you look at this one:

http://dragonbound.net/static/js/DragonBound.compiled.js

Is i can see is that the main js file with al it's defenitions...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of the oage one can eaisly tell that it uses the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.tinyscrollbar3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/QTransform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bgpos.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/DragonBound.compiled.js?42"></script>
```

You can google for sockets in html5, QTtransform , nodejs and jQuery to learn more about these concepts.

The template on which it has been built is HTML5 boiler plate.